# Register account feature in Python app returns "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python

When you run this python file and then register an account, it keeps giving me:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\***\***\***\***\___\accounts\accounts.txt'

How can I fix this? I'm new to Python. I learnt the files through tutorials.

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import os
import time
from colorama import Fore

#======================================================================#
clearConsole= lambda: os.system("cls")
#======================================================================#
def register():
    
    firstname = input(Fore.CYAN + "Enter your first name: " + Fore.WHITE).lower()
    print(Fore.GREEN + "First name set to: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + firstname)
    surname = input(Fore.CYAN + "Enter your surname: " + Fore.WHITE).lower()
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Surname set to: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + surname)
    
    age = input(Fore.CYAN + "Enter your age: " + Fore.WHITE)
    if not str.isdecimal(age):
        print(Fore.RED + "Age must be a number. Please try again.")
        age = input(Fore.CYAN + "Enter your age: " + Fore.WHITE)
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Age set to: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + age)
    
    password = input(Fore.CYAN + "Enter a strong password: " + Fore.WHITE)
    if len(password) < 6:
        print(Fore.RED + "Password should be between 6 to 18 characters long.")
        password = input(Fore.CYAN + "Enter a strong password: " + Fore.WHITE)
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Password is: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + password)

    username = firstname[:1] + surname + age
    username.lower()
    
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Your username is: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + username + Fore.GREEN + "\nYour password is: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + password + Fore.GREEN + "\nYour firstname is: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + firstname + Fore.GREEN + "\nYour surname is: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + surname + Fore.GREEN + "\nYour age is: " + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + age)
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    global encryptedUsername, encryptedPassword, encryptedFirstname, encryptedSuraname, encryptedAge
    
    encryptedUsername = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in username)
    encryptedPassword = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in password)
    encryptedFirstname = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in firstname)
    encryptedSuraname = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in surname)
    encryptedAge = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in age)
    
    if not str.isdecimal(age) or len(password) < 6:
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Error occured, please try again.", 3)
        loginMenu()
    else:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        accountsFolder = "accounts"
        accountFile = "accounts.txt"
        fileAccDirect = os.path.join(cwd, accountsFolder, accountFile)
        
        directoryExists = os.path.exists(fileAccDirect)
        
        if directoryExists == False:
            
            os.mkdir(fileAccDirect)
            
            with open(f"{fileAccDirect}", "a", newline = "") as myFile:
                writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                writer.writerow([encryptedUsername, encryptedPassword, encryptedFirstname, encryptedSuraname, encryptedAge])
                myFile.close()
            
                clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Account successfully made. Please login now.", 3)
                clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 2)
                loginMenu()
            
        elif directoryExists == True:
            with open(f"{fileAccDirect}", "a", newline = "") as myFile:
                writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                writer.writerow([encryptedUsername, encryptedPassword, encryptedFirstname, encryptedSuraname, encryptedAge])
                myFile.close()
            
                clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Account successfully made. Please login now.", 3)
                clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 2)
                loginMenu()
#======================================================================#
def databaseOptionMenu():
    
    print(Fore.WHITE + "#========================================#   #==============>>")
    print("|" + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "   Please select what you want to do.   " + Fore.WHITE + "|   |" + Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + "   Logged in as:")
    print(Fore.WHITE + "|                                        |   |   " + Fore.MAGENTA + f"{user0}" + Fore.WHITE)
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "       Press 1 to create a table        "+ Fore.WHITE + "|   #==============>>")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "         Press 2 to Load table          " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "         Press 3 to Add Student         " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "        Press 4 to Remove Student       " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "        Press 5 to Search Student       " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "                                        " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "     Press 6 to see account details     " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "           Press 7 to Log out           " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "      Press 8 to exit the program       " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("#========================================#")
    
    selection2 = input(Fore.GREEN + f"[{user0}] >>> " + Fore.WHITE)
        
    if selection2 == "7":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Logging out...", 2)
        loginMenu()
    elif selection2 == "6":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 2)
        
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        file = open(f"{cwd}\\accounts\\accounts.txt", "r")
        
        detailsList = []
    
        for line in file:
            detailsList.append(line.split(","))
    
        for details in detailsList:

            encryptedUsername = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in user0)
            encryptedPassword = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in pass0)
            
            if encryptedUsername == details[0] and encryptedPassword == details[1]:
                decryptedUsername = "".join(chr(ord(char)-3) for char in details[0])
                decryptedPassword = "".join(chr(ord(char)-3) for char in details[1])
                decryptedFirstname = "".join(chr(ord(char)-3) for char in details[2])
                decryptedSurname = "".join(chr(ord(char)-3) for char in details[3])
                decryptedAge = "".join(chr(ord(char)-3) for char in details[4])
                print(Fore.WHITE + "#=========================>>")
                print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "Username: " + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f"{decryptedUsername}")
                print(Fore.WHITE + "#=========================>>")
                print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "Password: " + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f"{decryptedPassword}")
                print(Fore.WHITE + "#=========================>>")
                print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "Firstname: " + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f"{decryptedFirstname}")
                print(Fore.WHITE + "#=========================>>")
                print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "Surname: " + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f"{decryptedSurname}")
                print(Fore.WHITE + "#=========================>>")
                print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "Age: " + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f"{decryptedAge}")
                print(Fore.WHITE + "#=========================>>")
                print(Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "\nPress enter to go back...")
                selection1 = input(Fore.GREEN + "[Info] >>> " + Fore.WHITE)

                if not selection == "":
                    clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 2)
                    databaseOptionMenu()
    elif selection2 == "5":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.YELLOW + "Still coding...", 2)
        databaseOptionMenu()
    elif selection2 == "4":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.YELLOW + "Still coding...", 2)
        databaseOptionMenu()
    elif selection2 == "3":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.YELLOW + "Still coding...", 2)
        databaseOptionMenu()
    elif selection2 == "2":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.YELLOW + "Still coding...", 2)
        databaseOptionMenu()
    elif selection2 == "1":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.YELLOW + "Still coding...", 2)
        databaseOptionMenu()
    if selection2 == "8":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Exiting program..." + Fore.RESET, 2)
        exit()
    elif not selection == "[1-8]":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Please select from 1 to 8.", 2)
        databaseOptionMenu()
#======================================================================#
def login():
    
    global user0
    user0 = input(Fore.CYAN + "Username: " + Fore.WHITE).lower()
    global pass0
    pass0 = input(Fore.CYAN + "Password: " + Fore.WHITE)
    
    encryptedUsername = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in user0)
    encryptedPassword = "".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in pass0)
    
    try:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        file = open(f"{cwd}\\accounts\\accounts.txt", "r")
    except:
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Account doesn't exist. Please register an account.", 3)
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 2)
        loginMenu()
        
    detailsList = []
    line = 0
    for line in file:
        detailsList.append(line.split(","))

    loggedIn = False

    for details in detailsList:
        if encryptedUsername == details[0] and encryptedPassword == details[1]:
            loggedIn = True
            break

    if loggedIn:
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Successfully logged in.", 2)
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 1)
        databaseOptionMenu()
    else:
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Incorrect password or username. Please try again.", 2)
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 1)
        loginMenu()
#======================================================================#
def loginMenu():
    
    print(Fore.WHITE + "#===================================#")
    print("|" + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "    Welcome to Python Database!    " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|                                   |")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "       Press 1 to Register         " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "        Press 2 to Login           " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|                                   |")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "      Press 3 for help menu        " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("|                                   |")
    print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "    Press 4 to exit the program    " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
    print("#===================================#")
    
    global selection 
    selection = input(Fore.GREEN + "[PyDatabase] >>> " + Fore.WHITE)
    
    if selection == "1":
        register()
    elif selection == "2":
        login()
    elif selection == "3":
        clearConsole()
        print(Fore.WHITE + "#-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=" + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "Help Menu" + Fore.WHITE + "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-#")
        print("|                                                                             |")
        print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "            First time using? Start by registering an account.               " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
        print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "          To do that you need to press 1, and enter your details             " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
        print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "             If your already a user then press 2 to login.                   " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
        print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "       To view your account details when your're logged in press 5.          " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
        print("|" + Fore.BLUE + "       To log out from your account press 6, when your're logged in.         " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
        print("|                                                                             |")
        print("|" + Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "                          Press enter to go back                             " + Fore.WHITE + "|")
        print("#-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-#")
        
        selection1 = input(Fore.GREEN + "[Help] >>> " + Fore.WHITE)
        
        if not selection == "":
            clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.WHITE + "Loading...", 2)
            loginMenu()
            
    elif selection == "4":
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Exiting program..." + Fore.RESET, 2)
        exit()
    else:
        clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(Fore.RED + "Please select from 1 to 4.", 3)
        loginMenu()
#======================================================================#
def clearConsoleMessageAndTimer(message, seconds):
    clearConsole()
    print(message)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    clearConsole()
#======================================================================#
clearConsole()
loginMenu()
```

Comment: Please, provide [mre]. The whole question can be just 2 lines. Do you really want the file location relative to current working directory or relative to script path? Does `'D:\\\\\___\accounts\accounts.txt'. ` looks like correct path to you? And always post the full traceback you get.

Comment: I want the the folder to be made in the same directory as the python file. The folder being made is called account and inside of that another file will be made called account.txt. you can find this in the register function.